# Stop page load at specified time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to debug an element that loads about for the first .5 - 1 second on page load. It completely disappears after that; I am wondering if there is any way at all I can stop the page while it's loading at a certain time, either with a script or emulator so I can track down this element with developer tools.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the javascript with either Google developer tools or Mozilla firebug?

Comment: Yes, I have - there isn't an error with any script. It's simple a legacy thing, but it disappears before i can grab the selector and track it down

Comment: You can try inline HTML Javascript immediately after the offending element and set your debugger breakpoint there.

Comment: Set a DOM modification breakpoint in the DOM inspector.

Comment: @jdphenix well there is no offending element in the markup, or else I would just delete it (lol) it is being generated from somewhere > and then pushed on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`window.stop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop) to stop window loading, if that is what you are looking for.

It sounds like it would be easier to pause the script execution with the browsers javascript debugger though, by setting some breakpoints instead of manually inserting a stop statement.

Comment: can I allow the page to load UNTIL a certain point? Say, ,3 seconds and then stop as is?

Comment: @Nooneknows I think adding something like `<script>setTimeout(window.stop, 300);</script>` at the very top of the document should work.

Answer (score 1):

Second attempt, now that I understand your question a little better.

You can use a `MutationObserver` to output changes to the DOM.  Something as simple as

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    console.log(mutation);
  });
})
observer.observe(document.body, {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true,
  subtree: true
});

var hiders = document.querySelectorAll('.hider'), 
    hiders = Array.prototype.slice.call(hiders);

hiders.forEach(function(el) { 
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el); 
});
```

```html
<div class="hider"></div>
<div class="hider"></div>
```

in the window's `load` handler will work, and will output a [`MutationRecord`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationRecord) on each change. I'd bet one of those will be your element (specifically, the `removedNodes` of the record.) The browser console for this snippet will have what you'll see if you use this.